# Problem plotting line at price coordinates

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a simple indicator displaying vertical and
horizontal lines.
The vertical line should be plotted at the new york open price which
I am getting from a timestamp comparison, however the lines y coordinate
is not correct. Any help highly appreciated as I am struggling for a while now.

```
//@version=4
study("Sessions",overlay=true, scale=scale.none)
t1 = timestamp("GMT", year, month, dayofmonth, 0, 00, 00)
t2 = timestamp("GMT-5", year, month, dayofmonth, 0, 00, 00)

backLook = 86400000 * 1.5

displayCondition = timeframe.isdwm == false and (time > timenow - backLook)

vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) => // Verticle Line, 54 lines maximum allowable per indicator
    return = line.new(BarIndex, -1000, BarIndex, 1000, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth)

drawPrice(price) =>
    x = bar_index
    y = price
    txt = tostring(price)
    label.new(x, price, txt)

    // y position is always wrong, the label text displays the correct price though
    line.new(x1=t2, y1=y, color=#ec4069, x2=time + 86400000, y2=y,xloc=xloc.bar_time)

// ny open
if(time == t2 and displayCondition)
    vline(bar_index, #ec4069, line.style_solid, 1)

if(time == t2 and displayCondition)
    drawPrice(open)

// gmt open
if(time == t1 and displayCondition)
    vline(bar_index, #000000, line.style_solid, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem is the 'No Scale' mode. In order to disable that mode and fix the problem, remove the *scale* parameter from the *study* call:

```
study("Sessions",overlay=true)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain how to adjust the coordinates?

Comment: Just replace *-1000* and *1000* in *vline* with *low* and *high*: `line.new(BarIndex, low, BarIndex, high, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth)`

Comment: thank you but the problem is the horizontal line in the drawprice function, unfortunately this is not working

Comment: [Here is the complete fixed script](https://gist.github.com/fppden/f3428d7906c3f7eaf8e5279a8eb67ce7), it displays horizontal lines correctly, check it out please and let me know if it works for you. Thanks.